# WP7 App in Emulator closes for some reason

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, emulation

I was trying to inherit Control to some classes I was making the other day and I stopped programming, closed everything and today I came back to it, started and even without ANY modification it doesn't work. It starts and after a second or two it closes. Here is what is written in the console:

---

PID:0C180026 TID:0D890022 @@@@ ClockNot requested to reset alarmsPID:0C180026 TI
D:0D890022 @@@@ ClockNot has reset alarmsPID:0DB9001E TID:0C0E0022 @@@@ ClockNot
 is now exitingPID:0C180026 TID:0D890022 @@@@ ClockNot is now exitingPID:0B1F008
2 TID:0B5F007E Exception 'Raised Exception' (0xe06d7363): Thread-Id=0b5f007e(pth
=c0469548), Proc-Id=0b1f0082(pprc=c0560d00) 'EmulatorStub.exe', VM-active=0b1f00
82(pprc=c0560d00) 'EmulatorStub.exe'
PID:0B1F0082 TID:0B5F007E PC=40330e4f(coredll.dll+0x00040e4f) RA=00011c70(Emulat
orStub.exe+0x00001c70) SP=004fa96c, BVA=004fa9d8
PID:0D40002E TID:0D620032 Exception 'Raised Exception' (0xc0008005): Thread-Id=0
d620032(pth=c059bcb0), Proc-Id=0d40002e(pprc=c058a5e8) 'TaskHost.exe', VM-active
=0d40002e(pprc=c058a5e8) 'TaskHost.exe'
PID:0D40002E TID:0D620032 PC=44665ed2(mscoree3_7.dll+0x00065ed2) RA=446c28be(msc
oree3_7.dll+0x000c28be) SP=003ff074, BVA=035ac9c8

---

And here is an exception I get when debugging (but it doesn't let me see the code.However, it suggests using disassembler.

---

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll

Additional information: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:2502/ApplicationSessionService/ApplicationSessionService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

---

I am running it on my Laptop and using WiFi connection to the internet. After getting this message I went to my router's parameters and forwarded port 2502 to my machine (although I'm not sure why I didn't have to before) but it didn't work.

What do you suggest?

Comment: So why do you say "for no reason"? I see two very detailed reasons for the application to close.

Comment: It's kinda "no reason" because it worked the day before. And my computer had been only hibernated several times before I found out it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to access the url of the webservice in your browser? Seems like that webservice is not available anymore. Please check IIS if the webservice is still running. (Or in case of running this webservice from visual studio please check if cassini is still up and running and if it's running at the same port.)

Comment: I didn't use IIS so I assume I was using Cassini. But I can't find the option to change it to IIS or where to change the port. I don'y even know why it needs it. It's not for debugging because even if I run it without debugging it crashes.

Comment: Is the webservice in the same solution? Have you tried accessing the webservice url in the browser? What was the result? Can you build the webservice project and start it?

Comment: There is no such thing as webservice project. If I try to open that link, it says it can't connect. Which is kinda obvious, I think. But I found out what the problem was. It was Isolated Storage Explorer. I don't know why it crashes but it does (while it didn't before). At least now I know what is causing it :) EDIT: Found out that WP7 Isolated Storage Explorer service was not running. Probably it crashed for some reason and didn't start again.

Comment: Thank you Pius. It was IsolatedStorageExplorer in my case as well.